# Code optimization to reduce the number of API calls in java

Tags: java, api, optimization

I have a method name `getProjectswithPriority` that has two input parameters: `key` and `priority` and it has a API call in it to get data from the database:

```
  public Projects getProjectswithPriority(String Key, String priority) {
    // Here is an API to get records from db
  }
```

In another method, I want to get Projects with the same key but 3 values of priority, the way I implemented this is calling the function (obviously and its API) 3 times:

```
public Projects MY_FUNCTION (KEY){
///...
Projects HighProjects = getProjectswithPriority(KEY, "High");
Projects CriticalProjects = getProjectswithPriority(KEY, "Critical");
Projects HighestProjects = getProjectswithPriority(KEY, "Highest");
/// ....
}
```

I believe there is a more convenient way to implement this method, in order to decrease the number of API calls, such as using a for and getting all the projects and loop over them. But I don't know about the possible solutions to optimize this code. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: I would not optimize around poorly written APIs unless there is a noticeable performance impact.    I would keep the call the way you had it and suggest to the API maintainer to create an api like `getProjectswithAtLeastPriority` or `getProjectswithPriorities`

Comment: @erickson I have three API calls in one function, as I mentioned I want to reduce it to one API call with a for loop if it is possible or any possible suggestions. I feel multiple API calls is not perfect

Comment: @toppk multiple API calls does not make any problem in larger projects? I mean what if I have 15 types of priorities? Should I call the API 15 times?

Comment: @erickson I want to modify the caller. I am looking for a solution to reduce the API calls. If there is a need to modify the callee it is also okay! The goal is reducing the API calls. I prefer to get all the data first and then perform methods to split or map them like this example for key and priority

Comment: @Tindona  It is a balancing act.  IMO the biggest problem is when users of APIs don't talk to the maintainers of APIs (and the maintainers don't look at the API access patterns to discover inefficient usage).  I've had to use bulk API queries and do my own filtering because the correct API was too slow.  But we're talking tens of seconds of difference in query execution time, not the overhead of a few extra round trips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following changes:

1. Callers have hard-coded references to specific values from what appears to be a stable set of enumerable priorities. This makes them a good candidate for an `enum` type.
2. Alter (or overload) the `getProjectsWithPriority()` API to accept a set of priorities.
3. Alternatively, use varargs to send a set of priorities.

```java
enum Priority { LUDICROUS, NEGLIBLE, TRIVIAL, LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH, CRITICAL, HIGHEST }

public Projects getProjectsWithPriority(String key, Set<Priority> priorities) {
  /* Get projects from database... */
}

Set<Priority> important = EnumSet.of(Priority.HIGH, Priority.CRITICAL, Priority.HIGHEST);
Projects projects = getProjectsWithPriority(key, important);
```